# How to test a click event in the Jasmine Test runner in Backbone?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a spec in which I want to test if a method is called when a button is clicked.

I have registered the click event in the View file:

```
events: {
    'click #toggle': 'onClickToggle'
}
```

My test file looks like:

```
describe('Todo Item\'s view\'s suite', function() {

    let view;

    beforeEach(function() {
        const todoItem = new TodoItem({ description: 'Some Todo ' });
        view = new TodoItemView({ model: todoItem });

        const html = '<label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />Some Desc</label><button id="delete">Delete</button>';
        view.$el.html(html);
    });

    it('clicking on element or checkbox should invoke the onClickToggle method', function() {
        spyOn(view, 'onClickToggle');

        view.$('#toggle').click();

        expect(view.onClickToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I have referenced all the required files in the test runner HTML including jQuery, Jasmine, jQuery-Jasmine. But when the spec file is run in te browser, the test fails.

The following error is thrown:

```
Error: Expected spy onClickToggle to have been called.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/tests/jasmine/spec/views/TodoItemViewSpec.js:28:36)
    at <Jasmine>
```

Comment: does `spyOn(view, 'onClickToggle')` return a py, or convert original method `view.onClickToggle` to a spy?

Comment: As far as I know, it converts it to a spy. Can view's methods be spied on or can we only spy on model and collection methods? Because, when I checked for the assertion of the view's method, it failed, but in the method, I had invoked the model and collection's methods and when I asserted them to have been called, the test case passed.